# angular 2 how to set initial error state on form controls

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

When my html renders in Angular 2 how do I set all form controls to their error state if they are in error? To clarify in this sample code there is only one drop down. When the form loads it is non red / no required message. If I open the drop down and then click outside somewhere without making any selection THEN the red magic happens and I see the error message. I need it to be in error state/red with error message when the form renders for the first time. I guess I need to set error state on that control somewhere. Just don't know where and how. Please advise. Code is below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-error-initial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Programmatically set your control as touched by calling `markAsTouched()` in `ngAfterViewInit`

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.animalControl.markAsTouched();
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-error-initial-atr11t?embed=1&file=app/select-hint-error-example.ts

Comment: better use ngOnInit not ngAfterViewInit

Comment: @Eliseo please elaborate

Comment: @Eliseo if we were instantiating the `FormControl` I would agree with using `ngOnInit`... the error state on `FormControl` is generated post `user` interaction with the control/input... the `user` cannot interact with the control/input until after the view is initialized. We are simulating a `user` "touching" the field.. I see no problems with this being in `ngAfterViewInit`... saying "better" use ngOnInit for this case is very subjective. This can be placed in either one and it will meet the requirements of the question.